# series labels are one over another(overlapping)

Tags: highcharts

the labels are one on another(overlapping)
is there an option to arrange them correctly ? (my real data is dynamic, and number of series is also dynamic)

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/6kBQY/

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff']
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                borderRadius: 5,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(252, 255, 197, 0.7)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#AAA',
                y: -6
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [10, 20, 30, 25, 15, 5]        
    },{
        data: [11, 22, 33, 20, 10, 0]       
    }]
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can use small workaround like here

```
function StaggerDataLabels(series) {
    sc = series.length;
    if (sc < 2) return;

    for (s = 1; s < sc; s++) {
        var s1 = series[s - 1].points,
            s2 = series[s].points,
            l = s1.length,
            diff, h;

        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (s1[i].dataLabel && s2[i].dataLabel) {
                diff = s1[i].dataLabel.y - s2[i].dataLabel.y;
                h = s1[i].dataLabel.height + 2;

                if (isLabelOnLabel(s1[i].dataLabel, s2[i].dataLabel)) {
                    if (diff < 0) s1[i].dataLabel.translate(s1[i].dataLabel.translateX, s1[i].dataLabel.translateY - (h + diff));
                    else s2[i].dataLabel.translate(s2[i].dataLabel.translateX, s2[i].dataLabel.translateY - (h - diff));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//compares two datalabels and returns true if they overlap


function isLabelOnLabel(a, b) {
    var al = a.x - (a.width / 2);
    var ar = a.x + (a.width / 2);
    var bl = b.x - (b.width / 2);
    var br = b.x + (b.width / 2);

    var at = a.y;
    var ab = a.y + a.height;
    var bt = b.y;
    var bb = b.y + b.height;

    if (bl > ar || br < al) {
        return false;
    } //overlap not possible
    if (bt > ab || bb < at) {
        return false;
    } //overlap not possible
    if (bl > al && bl < ar) {
        return true;
    }
    if (br > al && br < ar) {
        return true;
    }

    if (bt > at && bt < ab) {
        return true;
    }
    if (bb > at && bb < ab) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/menXU/7/